# Servlet redirect to URL with UTF-8 (or HTTP header with UTF-8) - seen on Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, redirect, utf-8

Here is my code (seen on Google App Engine)

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {       
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("testHeader1", "hi");  // Works fine
    response.setHeader("testHeader2", "שלום"); // Header not visible on Chrome client
    response.sendRedirect("/myUrl#שלום"); // Redirect does not work on browser (302 sent but Location header is absent)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RFC 2047` specifies about non-ASCII characters in headers, but most of the servers and browsers does not support yet.

So, if you want to send non-ASCII characters, you should be encoding the text to ASCII and send.

You can use `java.net.URLEncoder` to encode while redirecting and `java.net.URLDecoder` to decode at the other end.

Comment: Thanks - but then how do I redirect then to a URL which includes non-ASCII characters (e.g. in the # fragment)

Comment: Edited my answer. please check

Comment: Thanks but you can't explicitly "decode" a 302 redirect Location since the browser will process that, not my client

Comment: In redirect response what is the use of sending custom headers?

Comment: But I found that if I redirect to a Url encoded version of the # fragment the browser accepts that redirect ok so this workaround is ok - so I'm accepting the answer thanks.